# Accessing Azure Service Bus Queue from Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, servicebus, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I can't access Azure Service Bus Queue from Azure Website once deployed to the cloud. **While running on localhost, if works fine**, I can send a message to the queue, but if I deploy the application, on the remote server I am getting an exception while creating QueueClient:

> "The socket connection was aborted because an asynchronous send to the
>   socket did not complete within the allotted timeout of
>   00:00:59.4820817. The time allotted to this operation may have been a
>   portion of a longer timeout."

I am using **QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString)** method. The debugger shows that everything is fine with the connectionString variable.

The connection string is:

> Endpoint=sb://[removed].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=[removed]

I have tried to set "Copy Local = True" to all references without success.
I am using WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 2.6.4 nuget.

Also, the exception is not raised on **NamespaceManager.QueueExists(name)** if the queue exists, but exception is raised on **NamespaceManager.CreateQueue(name)** if it does not exist.

Anyone has experienced such problem? Thanks in advance for any tips.

**UPDATE 1:**

For clarification, I am providing the block of code and the trace output:

```csharp
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("BEGIN");
var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(this.configuration.ServiceBusConnectionString, "points");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(this.configuration.ServiceBusConnectionString);
queueClient.Send(new BrokeredMessage());   
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("END");
```

Produces the output:

- Connecting to Application logs ...
- 2015-03-29T01:40:29  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
- Application: 2015-03-29T01:40:41  PID[1952] Error BEGIN
- Application: 2015-03-29T01:40:44  PID[1952] Error Endpoint=sb://[removed-before-posting].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=[removed-before-posting]
- Application: 2015-03-29T01:41:48  PID[1952] Error The socket
  connection was aborted because an asynchronous send to the socket did
  not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.5586593. The
  time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
  timeout.

**UPDATE 2**

There are no connectivity issues while using Azure Storage API or SQL server.

**UPDATE 3**

Both, website instance and service bus namespace are created in North Europe region.

Comment: So, when you reach the point of passing the connectionString parameter, the variable holding is populated with what you describe above? Can you share: 1) Where do you store the connectionString? 2) How do you read it and assign it to that variable?

Comment: And also, how do you initialize the namespaceManager?

Comment: Yes, at the point of passing the connection string parameter, the variable is holding the correct connection string, mentioned in my main post. 1. I am storing a connection string in web.config and 2) I am using CloudConnectionManager to get it.

Comment: var manager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
    if (!manager.QueueExists("Points"))
    {
    // removed
    }
    // no exceptions at this point.

Comment: I really can't see anything weird. Can you test with the sample provided -> http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/ and see if that works (create a new namespace etc.). At least we can narrow down if it's a code issue or an SB issue with the namespace.

Comment: Couple minutes ago I tested a new namespace on US region. The same problem. The only thing I haven't tried is to host a website on different region.

Comment: Can you test with the sample as well? The only other thing I can imagine is that the SAS key you use doesn't allow you to do anything more than reading. The default allows everything and you can't touch it, so I don't think that it.

Comment: It should not be SAS key issue, because it works just fine when I run the application on the development fabric with the same connection string.

Comment: I can confirm the network problem - North Europe hosted Azure Website **can't** access Service Bus Queues in at least two, North Europe and Central US regions. A website, hosted in Central US **can** access Service Bus Queues in at least one, North Europe region.

Comment: That is seriously weird. I would suggest you open a support ticket with the highest severity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74024/discussion-between-zygimantas-and-panagiotis-kefalidis).

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to get the connection strings (that are available in the Azure UI) for Queues to work either, but I found that when I use a Powershell command

```
Get-AzureSBNamespace -Name $servicebusNamespace
```

to get the connection string, it comes up with a completely different connection string that actually works. So now I use the following code to provision all my Service Bus Queues: [createServiceBusQueue.ps1](https://gist.github.com/eccountable/102898645ee69c9d4240c33ec4f80134)